# How to handle incomplete file uploads when user disconnects from website in React-Express app?

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, axios, multer

I just wanna know The theory of How to handle File Uploading. Let's Say we make a Website Using React and Express that can upload Files to Our Storage. so some Users come To upload 10 Files and Started Uploading that 10Files But in the middle of the file uploading ( at the 4th file Uploading ) User disconnected from our website. so 3 Files are successfully Uploaded to our Storage but the Other 7 File Are not. So those 3 Files are useless. we need to remove that files from our Storage how to do this? we cant Send a Request To the Client Side because the client is Offline So how to make that? I mean express JS doesn't know that as well because that Does only incoming FIles Uploading. we cant do Like ComponentDidmount because if the user turns off his Computer we can't send anything to the client side. please Tell me How to handle This.

we need to handle this If the User and Our website Connection are Lost mean
user closes the Tab,
User Close the Browser,
The user Turns off the Device,
user Turns off Network,
basically, we need to handle these

Front-End: React JS
Back-End: Express JS
 
HTTP Request: Axios (for React)
File Save: multer (for Express)

everything Not Working because client offline